# Datatables Ajax and Laravel 4 - Tables not rendering, Ajax Error

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have been banging my head all last night and today. I have a Laravel 4.2 project where I have larger tables (2000+) records for some of my users. I want to use the ajax features to pull data dynamically. I used the PHP example from datatables but I am getting a '' with no response in the Network tab of Firefox inspector

Here is my jquery on the page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#table_large').dataTable({

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/pets/records/data/",
            "type": "POST"
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my Route:

```
 Route::post('/pets/records/data/', 'PetsController@ajax');
```

And here is my Repository:

```
public function ajax(){



    $aColumns = array( 'custom_id', 'pet_name', 'pet_type', 'age', 'breed','gender','status','intake_date' );

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "pet_id";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "pets";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = \Config::get('database.connections.mysql.username');
    $gaSql['password']   = \Config::get('database.connections.mysql.password');
    $gaSql['db']         = \Config::get('database.connections.mysql.database');
    $gaSql['server']     = \Config::get('database.connections.mysql.host');


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /*
     * Local functions
     */
    function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
    {
        header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
        die( $sErrorMessage );
    }




    /*
     * MySQL connection
     */
    if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = @mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );die();
    }

    if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
    {
        fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );die();
    }


    /*
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_POST['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_POST['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_POST['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            intval( $_POST['iDisplayLength'] );
    }

    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";
    if ( isset( $_POST['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_POST['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_POST[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_POST['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_POST['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                ".($_POST['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }

    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_POST['sSearch']) && $_POST['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( isset($_POST['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_POST['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_POST['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_POST['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_POST['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";
    $rResult = @mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";

    $rResultFilterTotal = @mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];


    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
    FROM   $sTable
";
    $rResultTotal = @mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
    //$rResultTotal = \DB::select(\DB::raw($sQuery));
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];

    /*
     * Output
     */

    if(isset($_POST['sEcho'])){
        $sEcho =  intval($_POST['sEcho']);
    }else{
        $sEcho = 0;
    }
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => $sEcho,
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    try {
        while ($aRow = mysql_fetch_array($rResult)) {
            $row = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($aColumns); $i++) {
                switch($aColumns[$i]){
                    case 'version':
                        /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                        $row[] = ($aRow[$aColumns[$i]] == "0") ? '-' : $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
                        break;
                    default:
                        $row[] = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
                        break;
                }
            }

            $sanitized_row = [];
            foreach($row as $cell){
                $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($cell, mb_detect_order(), false);
                if($encoding == "UTF-8") {
                    $cell = mb_convert_encoding($cell, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
                }
                $cell = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($cell, mb_detect_order(), false), "UTF-8//IGNORE", $cell);
                $sanitized_row[] = $cell;
            }

            $output['aaData'][] = $sanitized_row;
        }
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Error: ';
        var_dump($row);
    }
    $json =  json_encode( $output );
    if(json_last_error()) {
        print "json last error: ".json_last_error().'\n';
        print "json last error msg: ".json_last_error_msg().'\n';
    }

    return $json;
```

}

I was getting an encoding error but I added a UT8 filtering which is no throwing an error anymore but not sure if its a solution of a problem. Does anyone see anything glaring with this code or does anyone have a better solution for Laravel 4.2? Thanks and let me know!

Comment: Why are you using deprecated mysql extension instead of PDO and Laravel's own PDO based DB Layer? See: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

If you're just trying to copy paste some example code, port it to PDO or Query builder and you're much more safer and a lot more compatible with newer PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by DataTables initialization code and question tag `datatables-1.10` you're using DataTables 1.10. However your server-side code uses POST variables used in DataTables 1.9. DataTables 1.10 sends variables with different names (see [manual](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)).

Also in DataTables 1.10 distribution there is a sample class (`/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php`) that simplifies server-side processing (see [example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)). However this class doesn't support joins and sub-queries. It should be fine for you since you're only using one table `pets`, use `SSP::simple` method as shown in the example above.

There is also a enhanced version of this class on GitHub ([github.com/emran/ssp](https://github.com/emran/ssp)) that should supports joins and sub-queries.